# Reading into an Array Multiple Times

Tags: c++, arrays, search, indexing

I'm having a little trouble with my code. It's pretty much supposed to open two files, and compare the first twenty line of the file "StudentAnswers.txt" [inputted as a char into a char array] against a char value in (each line of another file) "CorrectAnswers.txt" in another array at the same position (index). It's like a linear search, but the same position in the arrays. Then a report should be displayed, detailing which question the student missed, the given answer, the correct answer, and if the student passed (got >= 70%) or not, like the following:

Report for Student X:
 2 (A/D), 3 (C/D), 5(D/A)
This student passed the exam!

Then it should clear the SAArray, and feed the next twenty lines from StudentAnswers.txt, and start the process all over again. I guess the program has to determine the number of students from (lines of 'StudentAnswers.txt' file / 20).

I'm having trouble displaying the report, and having the array clear itself after the program. I'm guessing this can be done with a while loop and an accumulator for the number of students (to be determined by above equation).
Also, Visual Studio seems to go to "Missed __ questions for a total of ___ %", and then keep looping -858993460.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void GradeReturn(char[], char[], int, int, int);
string PassFail(float);

int main()
{
    ifstream SA("StudentAnswers.txt");
    ifstream CA("CorrectAnswers.txt");char CAArray[20];
    char SAArray[20];
    // char SA2Array[20];
    bool isCorrect;
    int correct;
    int incorrect;
    int counter;

    correct = 0;incorrect = 0;
    counter = 0;

    cout << endl;


    if (!SA.fail())
    {
        cout << "'StudentAnswers.txt' file opened successfully." << endl;
        cout << "'CorrectAnswers.txt' file opened successfully." << endl << endl;

        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;

        while (a < 20)
        {
            CA >> CAArray[a];
            a++;
        } // while loop to feed char into the array

        while (b < 20)
        {
            SA >> SAArray[b];
            b++;

        }
    } // while loop to feed char into array

    CA.close(); // closing "CorrectAnswers.txt"
    SA.close(); // closing "StudentAnswers.txt"

    GradeReturn(&CAArray[counter], &SAArray[counter], correct, incorrect, counter);

    return 0;
}

void GradeReturn(char CAArray[], char SAArray[], int correct, int incorrect, int counter)
{
    float percent;
    float hundred;
    int student;
    int catcher[20];
    int writeCatcher;   int starter;
    int catcher_size;

    student = 0;
    writeCatcher = 0;
    catcher_size = ((sizeof catcher) / 4);

    while (counter < 20)
    {

        if ((CAArray[counter]) == (SAArray[counter]))
        {
            correct++;
            cout << "Good job!" << endl;
        } // correct handling
        else
        {
            incorrect++;
            cout << "You got question " << counter << " wrong." << endl;
            counter >> catcher[writeCatcher];

            writeCatcher++;
        } // incorrect handling

        counter++;
    } // while loop to determine if a student got a question right or wrong

    static_cast <float> (incorrect); // float conversion

    cout << endl; // for cleanliness

    percent = ((static_cast <float> (correct)) / 20); // percentage
    hundred = percent * 100;

    PassFail(percent);


    if (PassFail(percent) == "pass")
    {
        student++;
        cout << "Report for Student " << student << ":" << endl;
        cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;

        cout << "Missed " << incorrect << " questions out of 20 for ";
        cout << hundred << " % correct." << endl << endl;

        starter = 0;

        while (starter < (sizeof catcher)
        {
            if(1=1)
            {
                catcher_size
            }

            else
            {
                cout << "";
                starter++;
            }
        }

    }
    else if (PassFail(percent) == "fail")
        {
            student++;
            cout << "Missed " << incorrect << " questions out of 20 for ";
            cout << hundred << " % correct." << endl << endl;

            while (starter < catcher_size)
            {
                if ((catcher[starter]) == -858993460)
                {
                    starter++;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "";
                    starter++;
                }
            }

        }

    return;
}

string PassFail(float percent)
{
    if (percent >= 0.70) // if <pass>
    {
        return "pass";
    }
    else // if <fail>
    {
        return "fail";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: You could consider directly returning True or False for pass or fail and skipping the string comparison. If you want to "make it look better" consider using an enum mapping back to pass and fail.

Answer (score 0):

To get a loop you should keep streams open instead of closing them after reading 20 lines.

As pseudo code that would be:

```
a = 0;
while(streams_not_empty)
{
    CA >> CAArray[a];
    SA >> SAArray[a];
    ++a;
    if (a == 20)
    {
        GradeReturn(&CAArray[counter], &SAArray[counter], correct, incorrect, counter);

        a = 0;   // Reset a
     }
}

CA.close(); // closing "CorrectAnswers.txt"
SA.close(); // closing "StudentAnswers.txt"
```

You would also need to pass `correct, incorrect, counter` by reference so that the `GradeReturn` can change their value and their by do the accumulation.

Like:

```
void GradeReturn(char CAArray[], char SAArray[], int& correct, int& incorrect, int& counter)
```

Further you shouldn't rely on being able to read exactly Nx20 lines from the files every time. A file could have, e.g. 108 (5x20 + 8) lines, so you code should be able to handle the with only 8 lines. In other words, don't hard code 20 in your function like `while (counter < 20)`. Instead pass the number of lines to be handled and do `while (counter < number_to_handle)`.

Something like this as pseudo code:

```
a = 0;
while(streams_not_empty)
{
    CA >> CAArray[a];
    SA >> SAArray[a];
    ++a;
    if (a == 20)
    {
        GradeReturn(&CAArray[counter], &SAArray[counter], correct, incorrect, counter, a);
                                                                                              // ^

        a = 0;   // Reset a
     }
}

if (a != 0)
{
    // Process the rest
    GradeReturn(&CAArray[counter], &SAArray[counter], correct, incorrect, counter, a);
}

CA.close(); // closing "CorrectAnswers.txt"
SA.close(); // closing "StudentAnswers.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem you have is you're trying to compare C-style strings with the `==` operator.  This will compare them essentially as if they were pointers to `char`, i.e. compare whether they point at the same location in memory, not compare the contents of the string.  I urge you to look up array-decay and c-string variables to understand more.

Specifically, `if (PassFail(percent) == "pass")` isn't going to do what you want it to.  `strcomp` [doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/?kw=strcmp), `strncmp` [doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/) using `std::string` variables instead of c-style strings would all work, but it would be better simply to compare `percent` to a value, i.e. `if(percent >= 0.70` directly instead of calling PassFail and comparing a string.

There are many other issues here also, you at one point call PassFail but do nothing with the return value.  The only side affect of PassFail is `cout << endl`, if that's what you intend, it's a poor decision and hard to read way to put a newline on the console.

Try asking your compiler for more warnings, that's often helpful in finding these types of issues.  -Wall -Wextra work for gcc, you may have to read your compiler manual...